# VBA Cancel send email sent by Gmail

Tags: ms-access, vba, gmail, ms-access-2007

I know that Google Gmail was a functionality to cancel the sent email within 30 seconds.

As I'm using this code to send emails from an access database, and via gmail, I would like to know if there's a way to use that functionality to prevent sending an email for mistake?

```
Sub SendEmail_Click()
Dim NewMail As CDO.Message
Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

'Enable SSL Authentication
NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

'Set the SMTP server and port Details
'To get these details you can get on Settings Page of your Gmail Account

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mysite@gmail.com"

NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword7"

'Update the configuration fields
NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'Set All Email Properties

With NewMail
Dim strPath As String
strPath = ".mysite/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/myimage.png"
.subject = "this is the subject"
.From = "<mail@mysite.com>"
.To = Me.EMAIL
'.CC = ""
'.BCC = ""
.HTMLBody = "This is my message body"
.AddAttachment "https://mysite/temp/contacts.vcf"
End With

NewMail.Send
MsgBox ("This email was sent!")

'Set the NewMail Variable to Nothing
Set NewMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The **recall option** is not enabled by default, you might need to [enable it](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-recall-an-email-in-gmail/).  It would surprise me if that feature is available programmatically through Google, but there's no reason you couldn't queue the message **on your end**, for as long as you like, before sending it to Google.  ...that's all Google's doing anyway.  Emails can not actually get "unsent", it's just getting delayed in case you change your mind,

Comment: @ashleedawg The idea of queue the message on my end is great! I had not thought of that. Any chance you post an example of that implementation?

Comment: I don't have any code for that sitting around but it's only a matter of setting up  a table to store the relevant information (ie. subject, body, recipient, datetime to send) and storing the messages there until the appropriate time. You could use a timer event on a form to check, perhaps once per minute, if any messages are due to send.  Sounds like a nice basic project to get you more accustomed to Access. If you get stuck on anything *specific* that you can't find answered online, be sure to post another question with the relevant code.